# How to bind different Mongoengine database aliases for Flask-Admin views?

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine, flask-admin, flask-mongoengine

Developing a web admin interface for an information system using Flask-Admin and Mongoengine, I need Flask-Admin's `ModelView`s for all my entities. The system uses **several MongoDB databases**. Let's assume there's two of them for the sake of clarity.

Normally, people manage such behavior using Mongoengine's [database aliases](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/connecting.html#multiple-databases). During initialization, we define several aliases for our Flask app using Flask-Mongoengine's configuration:

```
    from mongoengine import DEFAULT_CONNECTION_NAME
    # Local packages
    from config import CurrentConfig  

    SECOND_DB_ALIAS = "second_db"

    app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = [
        {
            "ALIAS": DEFAULT_CONNECTION_NAME,
            "DB": CurrentConfig.DATABASE_NAME,
        },
        {
            "ALIAS": SECOND_DB_ALIAS,
            "DB": CurrentConfig.SECOND_DATABASE_NAME,
        },
    ]
```

Now we can use `Document`'s `meta` field, which binds the database (represented by its alias) to a particular entity:

```
    class Entity(Document):
        field = StringField()

        meta = {'db_alias': SECOND_DB_ALIAS}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't suit my needs here, since **the same entities (represented by the same `Document` class) can be present in both databases**. I want to set the database I query against depending on the logic of the app.

Well, whatever. We still can switch databases dynamically using Mongoengine's [context managers](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/connecting.html#context-managers):

```
    with switch_db(Entity, SECOND_DB_ALIAS):
         Entity(field="value").save()
```

(Notice: unfortunately, it's [not thread-safe](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/788) at the moment of writing this question)

That's what I do in the rest of the application. The problem is that **I can't find a way to do the same in my Flask-Admin's `ModelView`s**. How to set the alias of the database to query against in this situation?

```
    class EntityView(ModelView):
        can_delete = True
        can_edit = True
        can_view_details = True
        can_create = True

        can_export = True

        # No such or similar attribute!
        database_alias = SECOND_DB_ALIAS  

        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__(Entity, name="Entities")

    admin = Admin(app, name='Admin Panel', template_mode='bootstrap3')
    admin.add_view(EntityView())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

Spent some time examining `ModelView`'s [source code](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/69018859ec871d211bbe992e0a7ca0829f7642a7/flask_admin/contrib/mongoengine/view.py), and, indeed, nothing like this was implemented. Well, had to roll up the sleeves.

We have to wrap all queries to the database with `switch_db` context manager. The Flask-Admin documentation contains [a list of methods needed to implement a model backend](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adding_a_new_model_backend/#extending-basemodelview). Thus, if any database query takes place, it's there.

By examining these methods' implementation in `ModelView`, we can find out that Mongoengine queries can be executed only in `get_list`, `get_one`, `create_model`, `update_model`, and `delete_model` methods.

Now we derive from `ModelView` and wrap those methods with needed context manager:

```
class SwitchableModelView(ModelView):
    database_alias = DEFAULT_CONNECTION_NAME

    # Override query methods to add database switchers

    def get_list(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with switch_db(self.model, self.database_alias):
            # It's crucial that the query gets executed immediately, 
            # while in the switch_db context, 
            # so we need to override the `execute` argument.
            kwargs['execute'] = True
            return super().get_list(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_one(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with switch_db(self.model, self.database_alias):
            return super().get_one(*args, **kwargs)

    def create_model(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with switch_db(self.model, self.database_alias):
            return super().create_model(*args, **kwargs)

    def update_model(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with switch_db(self.model, self.database_alias):
            return super().update_model(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete_model(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with switch_db(self.model, self.database_alias):
            return super().delete_model(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then we can switch the database in our views like this:

```
class EntityView(SwitchableModelView):
    can_delete = True
    can_edit = True
    can_view_details = True
    can_create = True

    can_export = True

    # Now it works!
    database_alias = SECOND_DB_ALIAS  

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(Entity, name="Entities")
```

If `database_alias` is omitted, default connection still will be used, resulting in vanilla `ModelView`'s behaviour.

I tested it. Works.

Although, I have some concerns about this code's efficiency and reliability. As I mentioned, `switch_db` is not thread-safe at the moment. The database is switched on the whole `Entity` class when entering and leaving the context. So, I'm not sure how it will behave under high load in multi-threaded Flask application and if there's going to be race condition problems.

If anyone comes up with a better approach to the problem or with any improvements to this code, I'd be happy to hear.